# How to customize a Maven deploy of a multi module maven project with simple parent

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Hallo I have a multiple module maven Project. Each project has it's own pom and the parent pom.xml has packaging type pom, all others jar.

```
Parent Pom (packaging pom)
  Module1 (packaging jar)
  Module2 (packaging jar)
  ... 
  Module_n  (packaging jar)
  Extension1  (packaging jar)
  extension2 (packaging jar)
  ...
```

Now i want to configure the projects, that all modules are put to a local repository like C:\repo\modules
and all extension put to c:\repo\extension\
and alle dependency jars should be put to c:\repo\lib\

My first try in parent pom is the following:

```
    <properties>
      <Repository>file://${user.home}\repo</Repository>
   </properties
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>Deploy/id>
            <url>${Repository}</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

The 1st problem here is, that all childprojects are put in an own directory named like the project name.
2. No dependency of a module or extension was deployed to the repository
3. I also need to copy some settings files from some projects to the repository. How I can do this. Thanks for you help!

Comment: My first question in this relationship would be: Why would you like to do such a thing? It sounds you are mistaken deployment (in the Maven sense) and building ..

Answer (score 0):

You should probably checkout the maven dependency plugin. Configure it in your main pom and on a per module basis specific where you want the dependency be copied. See:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html

As for you specific files, use the resources plugin to copy them. See:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html